# How to work with delayed get Http API Response in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await

In here i am getting a delayed response from this `this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params)` api.Therefore i am using `setTimeout` and `async/await`.But my promise is rejected.

```
bookingInfo = [];

  timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

This is where i am calling my API get request.

```
async getBookingInfo(dateType: string) {
    const params = [];
    params.push({code: 'dateType', name: dateType});
    params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
    params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-05-31'});
    return await this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).toPromise();
  }

getBookingDetails() {
    this.timeout(150057 ).then(() => this.getBookingInfo('BOOKING').then(
      bookings => {
        console.log(bookings);
      }));
  }
```

But I could n't get print my `console.log(bookings);`Promise is rejected and my get requests fail.This is the error i am getting [image]

How could i resolve it.

Comment: Why are you mixing async/await code with .then callbacks?

Comment: I want to hold my get http request until a response comes.It takes more than 2 min to coe the response from the API

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you want to achieve. You are waiting for 150 seconds, then do you fire off your http call, supplying `BOOKING` as datetype to the api? That will most likely cause the API to respond in a 400 (Bad Request), which will cause your promise to get rejected as it's not a 200

Comment: this.getBookingInfo('BOOKING')  BOOKING is my parameter.Actually i can't understand what 's happening there. In here i am trying to get response to console.log(bookings);

Comment: I added this.timeout(150057 ) inside getBookingDetails()  to wait for the response

Comment: Have a look in your NETWORK tab in Chrome dev tools, see what the response code is for that call. Your client is most likely timing out if it takes 2 minutes to respond.

Comment: In network call it 's waiting for a long time and it 's failing.How could i fix this to wait and get the respone

Answer (score 0):

Making the method async and await should be doing what you are expecting it to.

```
async getBookingInfo(dateType: string) {
 const params = [];
 params.push({code: 'dateType', name: dateType});
 params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
 params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-05-31'});
 return await this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).toPromise();
}

async getBookingDetails() {
 await this.getBookingInfo('BOOKING').then(
  bookings => {
    console.log(bookings);
 });
}
```

Comment: Then can i use async getBookingDetails() method inside ngOnit() method

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, let's change this code to be more fitted for Angular and avoid promises. No need to convert observables to promises via `toPromise()`

```
getBookingInfo(dateType: string): Oservable<SOME_TYPE_HERE> {
  const params = [];
  params.push({code: 'dateType', name: dateType});
  params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
  params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-05-31'});
  return this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params);
}

getBookingDetails(): void {
  this.getBookingInfo('BOOKING').subscribe(bookings => {
    console.log(bookings);
  });
}
```

This code is without promises and lets check does it work. If no - then we at least know that promises are not the reason.

Comment: Actually my problem is there s a delay in getting response.Therefore after some time it get failed in the network tab.How could i hold my request until the response comes